# Best way to deploy Spark?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

Are there substantial advantages to deploying Spark on top of YARN or EMR, instead of EC2?  This would be for research and prototyping, primarily, and probably using Scala.  Our reluctance to not using EC2 stems primarily from the extra infrastructure and complexity other options involve, but perhaps they provide substantial benefits as well?

We'd mostly be reading/writing data from/to S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us differentiate the differnt layers: 
There is the infrastructure layer i.e. on which (virtual) machines should the spark job run. Potential options include local clusters of machines or a cluster of virtual machines rented from **EC2**. 
Especially when writing a lot of data from/to S3, EC2 could be a good option as both services are well integrated and usually are run in the same datacenters (giving you better network performance).

The second layer is then software/scheduling on top i.e. what piece of software connects all these machines to schedule and run your spark job.
Here options include **[Yarn](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/YARN.html)** (being the scheduler from the Hadoop project), **[Mesos](http://mesos.apache.org/)** (a general purpose scheduler being able to also handle non-hadoop workloads), and **[Myriad](https://github.com/eBay/myriad/)** (essentially Yarn on Mesos).

A good comparison between Yarn and Mesos can be found [here](http://www.quora.com/How-does-YARN-compare-to-Mesos).

EMR gives you the option to easily spin up a Hadoop/YARN cluster. There even exist bootstrap actions letting you [install spark](https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx15AY5C50K70RV/Installing-Apache-Spark-on-an-Amazon-EMR-Cluster) on such clusters.

Hope this helped to answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

EMR is the "same" that EC2 but whit Hadoop installed on them. If you will not need Hive/Pig or Hadoop itself then I think you will pay the extra cost of EMR for nothing. Conclusion: if you only need Spark use EC2 better, you can get a cluster with SPARK with "a couple of clicks". You only need to use: spark-ec2 script to get it:

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html
- http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/exercises-strata-conf-2013/launching-a-cluster.html

Another thing is when you say YARN ... I think you have misunderstood the concepts: EC2, EMR and YARN . I explain myself: YARN (Yet Another Resource Negotiator) is one of the two option used by SPARK to run over a large cluster of machines. You can use [Spark on Mesos](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html) or [Spark on Yarn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html).

Please refer to here: http://radar.oreilly.com/2015/02/a-tale-of-two-clusters-mesos-and-yarn.html

Answer (score 0):

Where's using Spark on a mesos cluster that we spawn over spot instances which makes it very cost.

Also if you're using Spark to access S3 you may want to use [DirectOutputCommitter](https://gist.github.com/aarondav/c513916e72101bbe14ec) which remove some of th eoverhead that is needed when writing to Hadoop